# jquery seach for specific element and add class

Tags: jquery, css, find, element, addclass

I'm looking for a way in jquery (or CSS3 ?!) to check all .vertical class element if there are another element with the same class .vertical just before OR after.

Please check, i would like to add a .solo class on the element mentionned :

```
<figure>
<figure class="vertical" ADD SOLO CLASS>
<p>
<figure>
<h1>
<p>
<figure class="vertical">
<figure class="vertical">
<figure>
<p>
<figure class="vertical">
<figure class="vertical">
<figure class="vertical">
<figure>
<figure class="vertical">
<figure class="vertical">
<figure>
<figure class="vertical" ADD SOLO CLASS>
<figure>
<figure>
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: That's completely invalid markup? Not one single element is closed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach:

```
$('.vertical').filter(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if (!
    ( $this.next().is('.vertical') || $this.prev().is('.vertical') )
  ) {
    $this.addClass('solo');
  }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SwDnU/). Note the change: I've closed all those `<figure>` elements (and some others, like `<h1>`) as, unlike `<p>`, they do require the closing tag.

Comment: I think this is a type $(.this);

Answer (score 0):

```
var not = $('.vertical + .vertical');
$('.vertical').not(not.add(not.prev())).addClass('solo');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/RF63V/)